# Testing a ftp client program in Java

Tags: java, apache, ftp, ftp-client

I have a java app that reads files kept on a remote server using ftp protocol, I used the `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient`to write my ftp client side code, but I dont know how to test it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this answer is a bit late, but if you want to test FTP client code, then take a look at MockFtpServer (http://mockftpserver.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can test by putting logs after connect, login, listing files etc, and in catch block you print the stack trace until all your connections issues are resolved.